# Using dependency injection in Angular 2 to customize an attribute-based component NgbDatepicker

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-datepicker

I cannot comprehend how DI can be used to provide a specific constructor argument in a component that i have imported. The `NgbDatePicker` contains a custom formatter interface (`NgbDateParserFormatter`), which, when implemented, can be passed in the constructor to the component to display custom date formats.
I am using the NgbDatePicker component as follows:

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" ngbDatepicker
    name="dp-start" [(ngModel)]="startDate"
    #dpStart="ngbDatepicker" id="dp-start">
```

If I wrapped the `NgbDatePicker` in my own component, then i could pass the custom `NgbDateParserFormatter` through my constructor and apply it. However, i do not wish to have a separate component.

How can i configure an external component such as the `NgbDatePicker` through DI from Angular 2?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by substantial coding. Additionally, if you have the custom `NgbDateParserFormatter` you can pass it in at your top level module and it will apply everywhere.

Comment: @silentsod i edited my unclear formulation of the question - I meant without having to wrap the ´NgbDatePicker´ in a further component. So how would i pass it in? Simply by declaring it in the module's `Provider` list?

Comment: I'm unsure if it can be per module (I have it app wide and have not expiremented otherwise), I recall having to poke around in their source code originally to figure it out but you can list it as a provider. I'll put up a demo in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The ng-bootstrap team still doesn't have a demo for this so here's how you can provide a custom formatter for your NgbDatePickers via your NgModule providers array.

Custom parse formatter will have a **parse** and a **format** function which are required. **Parse** is responsible for the internal model information being set and **format** handles display.

**custom.formatter.ts**

```
import { NgbDatepickerConfig, NgbDateParserFormatter, NgbDateStruct } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

export class CustomDateParserFormatter extends NgbDateParserFormatter {
    parse(value: string): NgbDateStruct {
        if (value) {
            const dateParts = value.trim().split('-');
            if (dateParts.length === 1 && isNumber(dateParts[0])) {
                return { month: toInteger(dateParts[0]), day: null, year: null };
            } else if (dateParts.length === 2 && isNumber(dateParts[0]) && isNumber(dateParts[1])) {
                return { month: toInteger(dateParts[0]), day: toInteger(dateParts[1]), year: null };
            } else if (dateParts.length === 3 && isNumber(dateParts[0]) && isNumber(dateParts[1]) && isNumber(dateParts[2])) {
                return { month: toInteger(dateParts[0]), day: toInteger(dateParts[1]), year: toInteger(dateParts[2]) };
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    format(date: NgbDateStruct): string {
        return date ? `${isNumber(date.month) ? padNumber(date.month) : ''}-${isNumber(date.day) ? padNumber(date.day) : ''}-${date.year}` : "";
    }
}

// lifted out of ng-bootstrap
function toInteger(value: any): number {
    return parseInt(`${value}`, 10);
}

function padNumber(value: number) {
    if (isNumber(value)) {
        return `0${value}`.slice(-2);
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}

function isNumber(value: any): boolean {
    return !isNaN(toInteger(value));
}
```

**module.ts**

```
import {CustomDateParserFormatter} from "src/custom.datepicker-parser-formatter"
import {NgbDateParserFormatter} from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap"

<...>
@NgModule({<...>, providers: [
    { provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, useClass: CustomDateParserFormatter }
])
```

Note that this is all based off of [their own source code](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/c5625e8d8197ef989507cdc1a9675f943b346599/src/datepicker/ngb-date-parser-formatter.ts)

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sRppDh3kYCS0HxrRLS1B?p=preview)

Comment: thank you for your help; it worked perfectly. To clarify my understanding: the _CustomDateParserFormatter_ is being provided throughout the module to all components that require the original _NgbDateParserFormatter_. 
It would be interesting to know how it can be applied per component as well. I will attempt to explore this further.

Comment: @PhilCap have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can use component providers to only apply it to that component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendar',
  templateUrl: './calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, useClass: NgbDateCustomParserFormatter},
    {provide: NgbCalendar, useClass: NgbCalendarPersian},
    {provide: NgbDatepickerI18n, useClass: NgbDatepickerI18nPersian}
  ]
})
export class CalendarComponent {}
```